# Can an app admin be added via Facebook JavaScript or PHP API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Is there a way to add an administrator to a Facebook application from the API?

We have an app that we have full code access to, but are not able to access the admin panel in Facebook. The client unfortunately doesn't have access and has come to us for help.

I haven't yet found anything in the API that would allow us to add an app administrator and was wondering if anyone knew how.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can post to the Application's 'roles' connection via the API, documentation here:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/app/roles#publish

It's a HTTP POST request to `/<App id>/roles?user=<USER ID>&role=<ROLE>` using a user access token from one of the existing admins

Possible roles are 'administrators', 'developers', 'testers', or 'insights users'

You'll need an existing admin of the app to authorise it, and you'll need the app access token to get a list of who those existing admins are

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that existing admin to authorize it will be an issue.

Comment: There needs to be at least one admin or the app would have been auto deleted - if you have access to the app's source (and it's a webapp) you should have the app ID and app secret and can use the roles API to fetch the list of current admins - that should help you find out who the current admin is

Comment: The source doesn't contain the secret and the only one that knows anything about it was let go. Thanks for the help though.